# Django, how to test migration without creating new files / django_session row

Tags: django

I have an app called `Sliders` and have created the models. How do i run the migration, so just the database tables get created but no new entries in `django_migrations` table and no directory `migrations` created in app directory.

This is what i normally do:

After model is created then make migration file:
`python manage.py makemigrations sliders`

Then i run migration file:
`python manage.py migrate sliders`

This makes a migration directory in the Sliders app and inserts rows to `django_migrations` table.  How do i prevent this?  Just want the table to be created in database.

Comment: What do you mean a migration makes an entry in the `django_sessions` table?? Do you mean to talk about the `django_migrations` table?

Comment: my mistake, changed it to `django_migrations`. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to migrate something without generating any migrations or adding entries to `django_migrations` you can use the [`--run-syncdb` flag [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-run-syncdb) while migrating:

```
python manage.py migrate sliders --run-syncdb
```

This as quoted from the above linked documentation:

> Allows creating tables for apps without migrations. While this isn’t
> recommended, the migrations framework is sometimes too slow on large
> projects with hundreds of models.

A point not very obvious in the above statement is that this won't work if the app already has applied migrations.

> **Note**: I would like to remind you of the point already considered in the documentation "*this isn’t recommended*". Unless you really
> need to do this and know what you are doing I will not recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSTALLED_APPS` should be like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'sliders',
]
```

Try some commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations  # Check for changes, ignore if nothing
python manage.py migrate # Apply changes, ignore if nothing
python manage.py syncdb
```

If not, re-migrate DB

```
python manage.py migrate --fake sliders zero
python manage.py migrate
```